# How to normalize data for ANOVA and GLM?

Tags: time-series, anova, generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, normalization

I have a dataset of onset times of a certain bat behavior and I converted the time values (hh:mm) into fractions of 1 by dividing hh component by 24 and mm component by 1440.

> eg. 18:10 = (18/24)+(10/1440) = 0.76

I want to check for the differences in the onset of the behavior across 2 locations and to test the effect of months. The data is not normally distributed and I already tried Sqrt, Log and Arcsine transformations. None of them normalises the data. Can I use ANOVA or GLM for checking the effect of location and months for this data set? 
I am looking for suggestions for doing the analysis or for other normalisation options (if any)
My data set is here

> Location   Month   onset
>
> A  Feb 0.20
>
> A  Feb 0.15
>
> A  Feb 0.14
>
> A  Mar 0.22
>
> A  Mar 0.23
>
> A  Mar 0.19
>
> A  April   0.21
>
> A  April   0.22
>
> A  April   0.20
>
> A  April   0.20
>
> A  May 0.22
>
> A  May 0.22
>
> A  May 0.20
>
> A  May 0.21
>
> B  Feb 0.19
>
> B  Feb 0.13
>
> B  Feb 0.18
>
> B  Feb 0.19
>
> B  Mar 0.22
>
> B  Mar 0.19
>
> B  Mar 0.22
>
> B  Mar 0.20
>
> B  April   0.24
>
> B  April   0.21
>
> B  April   0.19
>
> B  May 0.20
>
> B  May 0.22
>
> B  May 0.19
>
> B  May 0.17

Comment: It's normality of *residuals* not the raw data that matters in ANOVA. Run a two-way ANOVA and test the residuals.

Comment: Also remember that what matters is the data are drawn from a population with normally distributed residuals, not that the sample data are normally distributed. Small samples such as this, even if drawn from a normal distribution, will not be normally distributed.